# Change window location with button click

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I've read the documentation on tabs examples of the firefox add-on SDK. I may be wrong, but doesn't the tabs API apply to new tabs?

There doesn't seem like there is a simple way to click a button **on a panel** and simply change the url of the current (main) window.

I assume I need a content script to accomplish this?

```
// panel.html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
    <script>
      function goToHome() {
          window.location.replace(http://domain.com/home)
      }
    </script>
</head>
  <body>
    <form id="frm1" action="" method="post">
      <div><input type="button" onClick="goToHome()" name="Submit" value="home"></div>
    </form> 
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tabs API applies to all open tabs. You can refer to individual tabs by index–`var tab = tabs[x]`–or the current tab with `var tab = tabs.activeTab`. Then you can set the [url](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/tabs#url) with `tab.url = someUrl`. Put this code inside the `onclick` property of a [widget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/widget) and you're good to go. All code goes in main.js, no content scripts needed.

If by "on a panel" you mean *inside* a panel, then yes, you'll need a content script for the panel, but not a page script as your code shows. See [scripting panel content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/panel#Scripting_panel_content). Example:

### main.js

```
var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");
var data = require("sdk/self").data;
var panel = require("sdk/panel").Panel({
    contentURL: data.url("panel.html"),
    contentScript: "function goToHome() {self.port.emit('goToHome', homeUrl);}"
    //OR
    contentScriptFile: data.url("panel.js")
});
panel.port.on("goToHome", function(homeUrl) {
    tabs.activeTab.url = homeUrl;
}
```

If you use `contentScriptFile`, then include `panel.js` in your data folder. This will get injected into `panel.html`.

### panel.js

```
var homeUrl = "http://www.google.com/";
function goToHome() {
    self.port.emit('goToHome', homeUrl);
}
```

Comment: If button click fires goToHome(), shouldn't port.emit be in panel.html? Where do you set homeUrl?

Comment: The `contentScript` string is injected as a content script. Content scripts are similar to putting it in `panel.html` (called a page script), but different in that it's a lot easier to communicate between `main.js` and a content script than a page script. If you want the script to be more complicated than a one-liner, use [`contentScriptFile`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/panel#Panel%28options%29). See updated answer.

Comment: As an aside, the reason that your code didn't work is that the window object referenced in panel.html is the little panel window, not the tab's window object.